# IIS ASP.NET application responds to IP but not to domain name

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, hostname

I've got a problem with IIS. I got a ASP.NET application there running and I am able to connect to it from local network (http://192.168.100.121:12002/) and from outer network too (185.91.165.134:12002 , connecting via phone, because router doesn't support this feature).
The thing is when I try to connect via a domain name queue.laststep.eu, it says error: timed out.
I've asked my friend to tracert this domain name and it finished at the router the server is connected to, so I suppose DNS is configured properly.
Does anyone got an idea what may be blocking inbound traffic? (Firewall is off, ports on our primary router are forwarded...)
I am attaching a screenshot of the site bindings(got to put it on 3rd party server due to low reputation...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6EZJ.jpg)
Thank you for help!

Comment: DNS won't handle the port for you. So in your case, map port 80 on the router to port 12002 on your IIS server.

Comment: Alright, thanks for answer, I will give it a try. Though when I was setting up DNS, I set up two records: A with IP and SRV with name and port. I did it with my TS3 server too and it worked perfectly. I'm just saying that becouse I would like to run two webservers from the same computer in the future. But I will try your suggestion and see if magic happens.

Comment: @LexLi thank you very much! Your suggestion works perfectly. But I still got one question: If I want to run two webpages on the same machine and the default 80 port is taken by one of them, will I be somehow able to access the second webpage via a domain name? I mean, the queue.laststep.eu now works, but what If I want another webpage running on the same machine to be servered under api.laststep.eu?

Comment: It really depends on what web servers you want to run together. But think out of the box please. You should learn that by setting up a reverse proxy behind your router, either upon nginx or IIS, you can then put a lot of web servers behind. Reverse proxy is widely used to distribute traffic to those web servers, and it can handle tons of domain names.